# Como verificar con PHP que el usuario realmente haya entrado al sitio y no sea el navegador que entró en segundo plano?

Tags: php, chrome, opera

La idea es enviar un mail al usuario que se registró en mi sitio web con link que contiene un token para verificar su mail.

sitio.com?token=letras_random

Al ingresar al link, php obtiene la variable token y revisa si está en la base de datos, verificando el mail del usuario.

El problema que me surgió es que con tan solo abrir el mail (sin entrar al link) mi navegador ingresa al link en segundo plano (supongo para cargar más rápido el sitio si el usuario ingresa realmente)

Al ingresar al sitio en segundo plano activa el script de PHP verificando el mail (O sea que aunque el usuario no haya entrado realmente al link ni quiera entrar mi sitio web ya le verifica el mail)

Como podría hacer para ver si el usuario realmente entró al link o fue su navegador quien entró en segundo plano?

Comment: La pregunta no se ajusta al formato del sitio, puesto que está basada en opiniones, todas perfectamente válidas. Dicho esto, mi opinión es que añadas otro nivel, por ejemplo, añadiendo un botón pulsable en la página a la que dirige el *link*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo que hice fue poner adentro del sitio web donde el usuario ingresa una funcion de javascript que envia ese token automaticamente en segundo plano por POST a otro archivo .php

Ese archivo php revisa el token y verifica el mail. El javascript del sitio donde esta el usuario recibe la respuesta y printea el resultado (Si se verifico o no el mail)

Answer (score 1):

Una posible solución es que en el correo de le envíes un código de verificación, así cuando ingresa a e link no se verifica hasta que el código sea ingresado.

La otra forma que veo posible es que se setea el password en el link de verificación así el usuario solo se registra con el email y a la hora de dar click en link crear el password para su cuenta.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.